# Are these tables in 2nd normal form? 3rd?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have the following tables in my database:

[image]

Above these tables (not pictured) is a Users table where the SendingUserId and ReceivingUserId are keyed onto (they are foreign keys).

Are these tables in a normalized form? I feel as if I'm missing something.. maybe the SendingUserId and ReceivingUserId should be a composite key in the UsersWithMessages table?

Comment: What do you need `UsersWithMessages` for?

Comment: That... is an excellent question. I was thinking that it's a many-to-many relationship.. could I just eliminate this table?

Comment: According to your `Message` table it's not `many-to-many`: it's `one-to-two`: each message has a **single** Sender and a **single** Receiver. If this is the case then, yes, get rid of `UsersWithMessages`. If messages can have multiple Senders and/or Receivers - remove `SendingUserId` and `ReceivingUserId` from `Message` and keep `UsersWithMessages`.

Comment: No multiple senders/receivers. Formulate a proper answer and I'll pop in the check. Great answer and thank you.

Comment: Why on earth is this question downvoted? Do people just mindlessly click downvote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as one message can have no more than one sender and no more than one receiver, you do not have a `many-to-many` relationship.

Since your `Message` table already contains `SendingUserId` and `ReceivingUserId`, just make them Foreign Keys (FK) and you would not need `UsersWithMessages` table at all.

You will have a simple two-table schema: `User` and `Message`.